# Facebook SDK 4.10 Read And Publish Permission android Code

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, permissions

how to put facebook readpermission and publish permission in single login. Here my code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email",  "user_friends", "user_games_activity"));

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
       public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        setData(loginResult);
                    }

       public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CANCEL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

       public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                });}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(
            BrainSpeed_MainActivity.this,
            Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
}
```

the callbackmanager always calling back when facebook activity are done.

Comment: _“how to put facebook readpermission and publish permission in single login”_ – you’re not supposed to do that; Facebook has deliberately split this into two separate steps. You are supposed to ask for publishing permission when the user triggers an action that requires it for the first time – not on initial login into the app already.

Comment: @CBroe did you mean that i need to put publish permission when i want to share/ update my score? in facebook game